# Time of SMB File Sharing Different in Linux and Windows

Tags: samba, time, smb

Good day, I am facing this issue where I hosted a Ubuntu with SMB File Sharing, FYI, all the files are feed from a microcontroller sensor to UBUNTU SMB Directory.
Then, I view with windows directory. It is ambiguous that the time of file creation isn't the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It may be a time zone difference. File time is kept in GMT but the two comps may show it differently being in different time zones

Comment: But both system time display correctly